# Unable to Create .cs Files in .NET SOAP API Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently working on a SOAP API project in .NET where I'm encountering an issue with creating .cs files.

I've attempted to repair Visual Studio from the Installer and have also downloaded the target framework of the project (.NET Framework 3.5) from Microsoft official page to ensure that the project was configured correctly, but unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.

When I right click on any folder/directory and select Add New Item, all I get is the following options:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SD6M.png)

Any ideas?